# How do I install nvidia-xconfig?

Tags: nvidia

Before this is marked as duplicate, I read the other question already and it did not solve my problem.

What do I need to do to install `nvidia-xconfig`?  I tried installing `nvidia-settings` but that did not work.  I also tried installing `nvidia-340` <*drivers for my graphics card*> and that also did not work.

I tried installing `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-340` and I had to wipe my system because `nvidia-xconfig` did not work hence my system crashed.  The driver I'm using comes from edgers because Ubuntu doesn't support it.  So now I have a fresh OS, and I do not have any nvidia drivers installed, I did however add the edgers repository and did:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the drivers for my video card `nvidia-340` and it loaded.  Not sure why because the first time I did that it didn't.

Comment: And I did exactly the same install of nvidia-340 and this time it didn't install.  I don't know what gives.

Answer (score 0):

You try to remove nvidia driver completely with all its settings and its xorg file. Then reboot and update grub and again reboot.

They add this repository `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and then do the `update` and `dist-upgrade`. This will update your all xorg libraries to the latest version as per your Ubuntu version.

The reboot it again.

Then you can install the nvidia-{your required version} from synaptic. Once installed just checked whether the nvidia is available in dash and reboot.

It worked out-of-box for me.

Comment: there is no nvidia driver install in fact, there is nothing listed as nvidia in packages at all.  this is a fresh install of os.  and i already did what you said i did the update and upgrade after adding the repository and nothing.